# Regarding the sound card issue on Ubuntu 22.04, there is an abnormality that occurs when playing a sound

Tags: 22.04, alsa

When I listen to music, I find that after playing for a while, there will be abnormalities. The abnormal sound is similar to the sound of no signal from a radio. After closing the music software, the abnormal sound will disappear. The same problem occurs when playing sound with other software for a period of time. When I plug in headphones to test for a while, there are also abnormalities. I suspect it is a sound card problem. My Ubuntu version is 22.04, kernel is 5.15, and the sound card model is byt-rt5651. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Which software have you tried to play music with?